# How to prevent BottomNavigationView animation from stuttering

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-architecture-components

(First of all: no, it's not a duplicate of mentioned question :P read, then push the button.)

I'm using the BottomNavigationView in one of my apps, loading Fragments with lists, which get their data from a ViewModel/LiveData/Dao. When selecting a Fragment via the BNV, it seems its animation somehow fights for UI-Thread time with the Fragment loading, causing it only to finish completely after the lists are displayed - which confuses me. I was under the impression, that LiveData calls are being handled async by default?

[Stuttering gif](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gwOuolk6LsDa8MKeL2AQ8aE2X7-vSw6J)

Is this a known thing?

ViewModel

```
public class ScheduleViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private final LiveData<List<ScheduleInfo>> arrivals;
    private final LiveData<List<ScheduleInfo>> departures;

    public ScheduleViewModel() {
        arrivals = SigmoDb.schedule().getArrivals();
        departures = SigmoDb.schedule().getDepartures();
    }

    public LiveData<List<ScheduleInfo>> getArrivals() {
        return arrivals;
    }

    public LiveData<List<ScheduleInfo>> getDepartures() {
        return departures;
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
public class ArrivalsFragment extends MainFragment {
    private ScheduleDetailsAdapter adapter;
    private ScheduleViewModel viewModel;

    private final Observer<List<ScheduleInfo>> arrivalsObserver = new Observer<List<ScheduleInfo>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<ScheduleInfo> infoList) {
            adapter.setData(infoList);
        }
    };

    public static ArrivalsFragment newInstance() {
        return new ArrivalsFragment();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        adapter = new ScheduleDetailsAdapter(getActivity());
        // using the parent fragment as LifeCycleOwner, since both its
        // child Fragments use the same ViewModel
        Fragment parent = getParentFragment();
        if (parent == null) {
            parent = this;
        }
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(parent).get(ScheduleViewModel.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        reObserveViewModel();
    }

    // remove and re-add observer until Google fixes the multiple observer issue
    // TODO: remove when Google fixes the issue
    // https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/47
    private void reObserveViewModel() {
        viewModel.getArrivals().removeObservers(this);
        viewModel.getArrivals().observe(this, arrivalsObserver);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_arrivals_departures, container, false);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rv_schedule_details);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return view;
    }
}
```

For info: I timestamped the ViewModel's constructor start and end (to rule out those calls somehow being on the UI thread - takes 1 millisecond).

**Narrowed down the issue**

After Robin Davies' answer, I tried the Android Profiler and although I get some GC events now and then, I don't get them all the time with the stuttering being there every single time. However, delaying setting of the adapter data in the observer by 100ms seems to let the BNV animation complete when switching to the ArrivalsFragment:

[No stuttering gif](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wXOTVKm6F-wCfaULKo6jAROPBq0z6TbQ)

All I did was changing

```
private final Observer<List<ScheduleInfo>> arrivalsObserver = new Observer<List<ScheduleInfo>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<ScheduleInfo> infoList) {
        adapter.setData(infoList);
    }
};
```

to

```
private final Observer<List<ScheduleInfo>> arrivalsObserver = new Observer<List<ScheduleInfo>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<ScheduleInfo> infoList) {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                adapter.setData(infoList);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
};
```

So it seems that this part of your answer

> Also if you post list results back to the foreground thread and
>   populate the adapter while the animation is running, that will force a
>   layout pass that will interfere with animation.

is the one I was struggling with in my particular case. While I'm a bit disappointed having to revert to using delays to make the animation fluent, I'm happy to have found the culprit and thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Have you tried the following: BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(yourBottomNavigationLayout);

Comment: you are doing some heavy lifting on UI thread. consider moving everything else to background thread (async task or anything you know) and load only ui elements on UI thread. the shutter will go away.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to disable the shift mode. I just want it to be fluent, non-stuttering.

Comment: @Rahul Kumar: I'm actuallly just loading the recyclerview and attaching the observer for the ViewModel change. I'll attach that piece of code, hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is common enough problem.

Assuming that you've already moved heavy processing onto an background threads...

If you are doing really heavy lifting on the background thread, you can trigger garbage collects, which can block the foreground thread long enough to cause stuttering. Also if you post list results back to the foreground thread and populate the adapter while the animation is running, that will force a layout pass that will interfere with animation.

Try using the CPU usage/profiling tools to see what exactly is holding up the foreground thread.

Solutions to consider would be to postpone population of the fragments until the animation is finished. Or pre-populate the fragment. Or maybe block the background thread while animation is running (perhaps). Or postpone the animation until the fragment is populated and laid out (which gets potentially unpleasant). If the problem isn't caused by a garbage collect, you could delay creation/population of the adapter until the animation is finished.

Comment: Is there any way to hook into the BNV's animation, i.e. do the fragment transition/adapter population when it actually finishes?

Comment: Seems delaying the data setting in the adapter lets the animation finish (see my edit for elaboration).